# Bridge to Kubernetes - connect to k8s HTTPS external service

Tags: kubernetes, bridge

I am trying to connect to HTTPS service available only on my kubernetes. For that I tried modifying the KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml by adding

```
env:
- name: InternalWebsite_HOST
  value: $(externalendpoints:my-super-internal-website.com:443)
```

Inside the pod i can curl the server eg.
curl https://my-super-internal-website.com/health
"Healthy!"

Bridge to kubernetes builds and creates tunel under under 55054 port.
When I curl https://127.0.0.1:55054/health
I am getting 404 Not Found | NGNIX rather than "Healthy!" message.

Is it possible to create bridge to external https using Bridge To Kubernetes or other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Try port and https to listen to local service by overwriting URLS. In your KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml file, below is the example

```
- name: URLS
    value: https://localhost:5001
```

You also might want to refer on this documentation as guidance to [Configure Bridge to Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/configure-bridge-to-kubernetes#local-configuration-using-kuberneteslocalprocessconfigyaml)

Comment: When you set the URLS environment variable, you're telling Kestrel which URLs it should bind to and listen for incoming HTTP requests. This allows you to specify one or more URLs that clients can use to access your ASP.NET Core application.  Maybe I did not explain what I am trying to achieve but my my-super-internal-website.com is second hand server not controlled by my app.